# Magento SEO friendly URL module only rewrites categories, products showing old URL

Tags: url-rewriting, magento-1.6

I have enabled the SEO friendly URL on Magento 1.6 and it's working perfectly for category.
But the product URLs are showing the old URL format.

My current product URL looks like:

> http://example.com/catalog/product/view/id/123/s/uppa-baby-vista-stroller/category/133/

What I should be like is:

> http://example.com/uppa-baby-vista-stroller.html

I've already re-indexed the catalog and cleared the cache, but it's not rewriting the products with the SEO friendlier version of URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are magneto default code.
After enabling SEO friendly URL don't forget to re-index from Magento admin.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that URL rewrites are not occurring,

**Are you running Enterprise Edition 1.13?**

If yes, more than likely your issue is with Magento's reindexing not occurring automatically. In 1.13, the reindexing occurs with a cron job. You must set up cron to run on your local server so that it will run automatically. To check if it has been setup, go to System->Index Management and check to see the last time product url reindexing has occurred. The reindex is what sets up the URL rewrites, you can check in the database to confirm that reindexing never happened (specifically in Enterprise Edition, look at tables enterprise_url_rewrite, enterprise_url_rewrite_redirect, and enterprise_url_rewrite_redirect_rewrite. See if these tables have rewrites for each of your products). If your products don't appear to have url rewrites in these tables, than reindexing never happened. My guess is that this is your issue if you are running EE 1.13. Follow this link to set up cron.

[how to set cron job for reindex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15355005/how-to-set-cron-job-for-reindex)

**If you are running Magento prior to EE 1.13 OR any version of Community edition**, make sure that SEO Friendly URLs are enabled AND that you have reindexed. If this still doesn't work, make sure the Magento Core code hasn't been modified.