# how to set cron job for reindex

Tags: magento, cron

How to setup cron job for clear cache and re-indexing in Magento. i don't know how to set the cron for re-index. but i saw some where every day cron runs defaultly in magento. still i am facing re indexing issues in my site. i need to clear cache also.[On Magento website](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job) here

they said that logcleaning and reindexing is commented out in the code so in which file I can un-comment to setup cron job fo log cleaning and reindexing?

thanks,
murali.

Answer (score 22):

To create the cron job, add the following to your cron file to reindex every day at 6am

```
0 6 * * * php -f /shell/indexer.php reindexall
```

Note: If you get an error telling you you’re out of memory similar to:

```
PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 7680 bytes) in …/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer.php on line 163
```

Try commenting out `php_value memory_limit` and `php_value max_execution_time` in your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i saw this in many forums. here only i confused. let me know can i create a file in my root directory. could you please tell me clearly.

Comment: You can access your crontab in the shell prompt by typing -- > `crontab -e`  ..  Then simply insert the line that @liyakat has provided.

Comment: also use your CPanel (or whatever your server has) to set your cron if you need to , it is a bit simpler and tells you if your syntax is wrong!

Answer (score 4):

I have tested my solution in my `cPanel 11.52.2.4`. So stay calm and do following:

Navigate to your magento2 admin area. And click over System > Index Management.

From the `Actions` drop down select `Update by schedule` and click on submit.

That is it from admin section. Now navigate to the cPanel area and do following-

1. Login to your cPanel
2. Under cPanel click on **Cron Jobs** under **Advanced** tab group
3. If you have already created a cron job, you can edit it, or create a new cron job.
4. Select the frequency to run the cron job, suppose **Once per week (0 0 * * 0)**.
5. Write the command to re-index the data, as

   **php-cli /home/username/public_html/sub_folder_if_any/bin/magento indexer:reindex**
6. Save it. As per your schedule frequency, the cron job will run.

If you want lesser frequency, but note that if you put less frequency it will consume the resource.

**Note:** Make sure you replace `<username>` with your cPanel user name and `/<sub_folder_if_any>` as per your magento2 installation directory. If you are not using any sub directory just ignore it

Comment: The question appears to be focused towards Magento 1.9. Your answer is about Magento 2.0. This answer is more appropriate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15355164/1439760

Answer (score -1):

We've the same problem and fixed change Megabytes to Bytes.
instead of set memory_limit 1024M we changed to 1073741824.

Looks like an issue at server... We're hosted at Media Temple using Plesk Panel

Hope you sorted it out sooner.

Regards